# Comparing densities of a feature for different classes when the feature is irrelevant to one class

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, kernel-smoothing

Let us suppose that I have a number of features. I design pdfs for every feature and every class, some of them by smoothing some histogram of training samples, others just by introducing the prior knowledge on how the feature should look like.

Now I want to know which is the most likely class for a given observation, based on the pdfs. I can state the following:

$$P(p_i\in C_i | F_i) = \displaystyle\frac{P(F_i | p_i\in C_i ) P(p_i\in C_i)}{\displaystyle \sum_{C_j} P(F_i | p_i\in C_j ) P(p_\in C_j)}$$

being $p_i$ a particular observation with feature $F_i$, $C_i$ the class I'm assigning to it.
What I've doing so far is just replacing $P(\cdot|\cdot)$ by its density function $\delta$ given that $P(\cdot|\cdot)$ is about $2\epsilon \delta(\cdot|\cdot) $ for a neighborhood $[F_i-\epsilon,F_i+\epsilon]$ and I can cancel out the $2\epsilon$, so I suppose it's just legitimate to directly take the value at the density function.

Now, there's one feature in particular in which I want to convey that I just don't care about its value in a very wide range, for one of the classes. It's an area, so say the area can be between zero and a large value. In other words, in this class we can find any area. In another class, there is a shorter dynamic range of the values the feature should take. The problem that I find is that the result of the formula before is always lower for the 'don't care' class because the uniform distribution extends far away and hence the value of the pdf is low at every point. My desired behavior would be that since I don't care much about the area, there should be a more fair competition among the two classes, and probably some other features in the classification process will make the final decision, but this way I just say that the problematic class is very unlikely for any input of this feature.

I could tune $P(p\in C_i)$ to be higher for the problematic class. However, in other features this is not what I expect. Any clues on how to handle this or pose this problem?